# apple mach-o linker id error for cgeventtap

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm trying to make a CGEventTap work. I think I've done everything correctly but when I go to run I get this error:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_tapCallback", referenced from:
      -[TestAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in TestAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have defined your `tapCallback()` function, but haven't actually implemented it. In other words, your `TestAppDelegate` class probably looks something like this:

```
#import "TestAppDelegate.h"

CGEventRef tapCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy,
            CGEventType type,
           CGEventRef event,
              void *userInfo);


@implementation TestAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    CFMachPortRef eventTapRef = CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap, 
                                                 kCGTailAppendEventTap,
                                                 kCGEventTapOptionListenOnly,
                                                 kCGEventMaskForAllEvents,
                                                 tapCallback,
                                                 NULL);
    // additional code

}

@end
```

Somewhere along the lines, you'll need to actually implement the `tapCallback()` function. If you have actually implemented it, say, in another file, make sure that file is included in your built target.

Otherwise, doing something like this should allow the program to run:

```
CGEventRef tapCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy,
                             CGEventType type,
                                CGEventRef event,
                                   void *userInfo) {
    NSLog(@"tapCallback()");
    return event;
}
```

Comment: It could also be the case that `tapCallback()` is defined in a source file that isn’t being compiled and linked to the target. If that’s the case, the source file must be added to the Compile Sources build phase.

Comment: @Bavarious: That's what I meant by `If you have actually implemented it, say, in another file, make sure that file is included in your built target.`

Comment: Ooops, should’ve read your answer more carefully. My eyes saw code only. :P

Comment: @NSGod: I made it work by including application services: `#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>`. Is this correct?